# Query on Signalling and STUN/TURN flow

Tags: webrtc, stun, sdp, turn

If a client is behind NAT, when does STUN/TURN come into play? 
1. After Peer connection object is created?
2. After setting local SDPs and sending it to the other client?
3. Before sending ice candidates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(2) -- setting the local description causes the ice process to kick off and that process includes gathering srflx candidates from the stun server and relay candidates from the turn server.

It is possible to kick this off at the peerconnection creation -- see [iceCandidatePoolsize](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcconfiguration-icecandidatepoolsize) in the specification.

[This sample page](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) illustrates the process.